# Inheritance problem Low level Design approach

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism

Suppose I have class hierarchy like the one shown in picture. Suppose I need to include a method `doThis()` that would have different implementation in classes `C` and `D`. But the class `B` need not implement this method.

Should I declare the contract in Class `A` and provide an empty implementation in class `B` or have another abstract class `X` which extends `A` and is being extended by `C` and `D`?

Thanks  [image: Sample Class Diagram]

Comment: I can hardly make out the image.

Comment: @Adriaan It was much larger before. It just shows: A is extended by B, C, and D. B is on the left. A is on the top.

Comment: @Adriaan Koster  Even I'm unable to see that. Corporate proxy blocking  image upload sites you see.

Comment: I see the image correctly now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If only sub-classes of A will use the method:
Make another abstract class that extend A and adds the method.

If you intend to have that method implemented in different class types:
Make an interface that declares the method, and then C,D should implement that interface as well.

Comment: Added a short description, when to use each option.

Answer (score 3):

Do not put it into `class A`. Use an `interface` that is implemented by those that need it.

Answer (score 1):

Make an interface called "doable". let your classes C and D implement this.

```
public interface Doable {
     public void doThis();
}

public class D implements Doable { /*implementations*/ }
public class C implements Doable { /*implementations*/ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not put it in A if you can avoid it.

The best solution can not be determined from the information you have given us. It depends on the context and meaning of the classes and methods.